# How to pass parameters in c from library linux

Tags: c, linux, parameters, parameter-passing

How to pass parameters from library in c programming language in linux?
I've tried this:

library.c code:

```
char test;
void GetParam()
{
  test = "Creating test string here.";
}
```

header.h code

```
extern char test;
void GetParam(void);
```

program.c code

```
int main()
{
  GetParam();
  printf("%s\n", test);
}
```

but test returns empty.

Comment: Did you include `header.h` in your `program.c`? And BTW, the type of `test` should be `char *` if you want to use it as a string.

Comment: Have you considered that you're trying to stuff a c-style string into a single char instead of a character pointer?

Comment: What compiler did you use? gcc generates warnings here, even without `-Wall`. And the result is a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

`char test` just stores one character. If you want it to store a string, use `char *test`

PS: I'm a beginner; please correct me if I am wrong.